# Where to Learn CISCO Router Configuration

Tags: networking, cisco, router

I'm looking for a course on learning how to use CISCO Commands to configure a Cisco router. Can someone advise me on how I might get started in learning this topic?

Answer (score 3):

As said above you may want to look at the CCNA studying litterature, there's also tools that may help you like [GNS3](http://www.gns3.net/) that allows you to simulate CISCO networks.

Comment: +1 Agree with GNS3. It's a powerful tool. If you want something similar, you can search packet tracer (but it's not free).

Answer (score 2):

One of Cisco big draws is that they are big on network education in general, with a slant towards their products.

What you want to look for is the CCNA (Cisco Certified Network Associate) courses or Literature.  Personally, I remember enjoying [Sybex's CCNA Study Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0782126472).  CCNA is the first level in their certifications and is an introduction to networking as well as their main operating system called [IOS (Internet Operating System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS) which has the command interface to which I would guess you referring too.

Comment: In fact the first level is CCENT which is ICND1 only (while CCNA is ICND1 + ICND2)

Answer (score 1):

I recently took a free 4 quarter course on cisco networking fundamentals. I actauly skipped the first quarter because it basically asks you questions like what is a computer CPU and what is dot quad notation. However in second quarter, the class had basic network setup for both computers and the routers in the network. Third quarter was switching, and unforunately I wasn't able to attend the 4th quarter.

However, at the end of that free course, (which I will finish) I'll basically be ready to take the CCNA exam, and have lots of free routing and switching hands on experience. This was all through the local community college, and I highly recommend that you go down to your local community college and do the same.