# CISCO Router configuration

Tags: networking, router, cisco

I'm looking for a course of `CISCO Commandes` to configure a router.

Is there anyone that can help ?

Comment: OP has posted duplicate question - see also http://serverfault.com/questions/147291/where-to-learn-cisco-router-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're looking to do, there's books for [just getting things working](http://www.dummies.com/store/product/Cisco-Networking-For-Dummies-2nd-Edition.productCd-076451668X.html), or for [studying Cisco technology](http://www.google.com/search?q=CCNA+ICND).

Answer (score 0):

http://pages.swcp.com/~jgentry/topo/cisco.htm
http://www.opennet.ru/soft/cisco-configuration.html
or anything on 
http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=configuring+cisco&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=configuring+cisco+router